# Calling on a specific text field with multiple common classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have been trying to use tampermonkey to automate a script for filling in a certain text box. This text box has many common classnames as a couple other text boxes and I don't really have the knowledge with js and jquery to find out how to call this specific field. The source for this field is

```
<input class="text ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" min="1" 
ng-model="crash.autoOut" ng-blur="crash.onBlur();" type="text">
```

I'm in this ride to learn and I have a very basic understanding of how this all works. I appreciate all the help!

Comment: So u want to find your input with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the classes attached to the input will not change, you can call it like this.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input.text.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty', function(){
    // Do something
});
```

or

```
$('input.text.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty').val();
```

Another (better) option is to find a parent with an ID or at least a unique class and call it from there:

```
$('#parent input.text').val();
```

Comment: so for the last option, I can see a parent div with a new class "input-box" as well as a parent of that div with an id of "auto-box". would the code then become $('#input-box input.text.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-not-empty').val();?

Comment: From the look of the classes they are from angular and some will change with change of input value.